# Android Package Name - Using Dashes

Tags: android, package

I was wondering if you could use dashes in a package name for an Android application?

Comment: Documentation on naming packages can be found here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, you cannot use a dash in your package name.

This is a great question to test for yourself. If you change the package name in your Manifest or class (I assume the wizard too) it will clearly create compile time errors.

---

The [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) that @vasart posted describes how to use an underscore in place of a dash, if necessary.

Comment: As I am not a developer it is hard to test for myself, but I appreciate the comments! Thanks for clarifying.