# Expo Eject working on iOS but not running on Android

Tags: react-native, android-studio, expo

I just created a whole fresh project using expo init and then ejected it with ExpoKit. It runs fine and smoothly on iOS but on android studio after I sync my gradle (successful) but when I try to run my app I hit the error below:-

```
/Users/hannzern/react-native-base/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:2: AAPT: error: attribute 'package' in <manifest> tag is not a valid Android package name: 'com.hannzern.expo-rn-base'.
```

I just checked my app/build.gradle and my applicationId is correct 'com.hannzern.expo-rn-base'. Is there something I'm doing wrong? I am currently on SDK 37.0.0 and with react-native at 0.61.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use dashes in your Android package name. For reference please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13753637/android-package-name-using-dashes).